# Identifying a quotient ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Consider the Quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+3,5)$.

Solution: I first tried to take care of $(5)$ in the above ring. Therefor we can consider  $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]/(x^2+3)$. Now and interesting point to note here is $(5) \subset (x^2+3)$. So, we can consider  $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]/(5)$. But this is just $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]$. Thus, am I on the right track? Is there a rigorous way to prove the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go abstract all the way, using the second-third (or whatever) isomorphism theorem successively:

$$\Bbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+3\,,\,5\rangle\cong\left(\Bbb Z[x]/\langle 5\rangle\right)/\langle x^2+3\rangle\cong\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle x^2+3\rangle\cong\Bbb F_{5^2}$$

Notice that in the second step we *actually* mean the ideal $\;\langle x^2+3\rangle\;$ in that quotient ring (or what is the same: the ideal in the integers polynomials modulo $\;5\;$).

The above is just an easy outcome of the rather important theorem:

An ideal in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ is **maximal** iff it is of the form $\;\langle p, f(x)\rangle\;,\;\;p(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ , with $\;p\;$ a prime and $\;f(x)\;$ *irreducible* modulo $\;p\;$

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field.  Hint: Is $x^2+3$ irreducible in it?

I don't think it is true in any sense that $(5)\subset (x^2+3)$.

Comment: $(5) \in (x^2+3)$ because 5(x^2+3)=0 as we are working modulo 5. Since $x^2+3$ is not 0, 5 plays the role of zero here. Regarding your hint, I found that tit is indeed irreducible. Thus, will the ring just be the set $\{ax+b|a,b \in \mathbb{Z_5}\}$

Comment: @JamesBond The ring will be that set irrespective of whether the polynomial is irreducible.  Irreducibility tells you much more.

Comment: Would we get a multiplication rule from the above info, that is $x^2=-3$. But wouldnt that be tru even if it werent an irreducible polynomial?

Comment: Ah! Since its an irreducible polynomial it makes the quotient ring  $\mathbb{Z_5}[x]/(x^2+3)$ also a field. This has 25 elements. Only field of 25 elements is $\mathbb{F_5^2}$

Comment: @JamesBond To be clear, that's $\mathbb{F}_{5^2}$.  $\mathbb{F}_5^2$ is what you get if you mod out by a reducible quadratic (and it's not a field).

Comment: I apologize it was typo and I indeed meant $\mathbb{F_{5^2}}$.